# Con Jquery ajax acceder a los objetos y sub arrays que estan dentro de otro array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

Hola estoy trayendo desde la api de mercado libre los datos de búsqueda, los recibo con ajax pero quiero acceder a al array `results` e iterar los objetos para acceder y darle formato a los resultados.

Me podrían ayudar lo estoy haciendo como práctica,

```
{
  "site_id": "MLM",
  "paging": {},
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "MLM863465344",
      "site_id": "MLM",
      "title": "Senwa Disco S301 32 Mb Rojo/blanco 32 Mb Ram",
      "seller": {
        "id": 183830593,
        "permalink": null,
        "registration_date": null,
        "car_dealer": false,
        "real_estate_agency": false,
        "tags": null
      },
      "price": 319,
      "prices": {
        "id": "MLM863465344",
        "prices": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "standard",
            "conditions": {
              "context_restrictions": [
              ],
              "start_time": null,
              "end_time": null,
              "eligible": true
            },
            "amount": 319,
            "regular_amount": null,
            "currency_id": "MXN",
            "exchange_rate_context": "DEFAULT",
            "metadata": {
            },
            "last_updated": "2021-01-18T21:08:00Z"
          }
        ],
        "presentation": {
          "display_currency": "MXN"
        },
        "payment_method_prices": [
        ]
      },
      "sale_price": null,
      "currency_id": "MXN",
      "available_quantity": 30,
      "sold_quantity": 0,
      "buying_mode": "buy_it_now",
      "listing_type_id": "gold_special",
      "stop_time": "2041-01-10T04:00:00.000Z",
      "condition": "new",
      "permalink": "https://www.mercadolibre.com.mx/senwa-disco-s301-32-mb-rojoblanco-32-mb-ram/p/MLM13429867",
      "thumbnail": "http://mlm-s1-p.mlstatic.com/889120-MLA41010292648_032020-I.jpg",
      "accepts_mercadopago": true,
      "installments": {
        "quantity": 12,
        "amount": 32.01,
        "rate": 20.4,
        "currency_id": "MXN"
      },
      "address": {
        "state_id": "MX-MOR",
        "state_name": "Morelos",
        "city_id": "TUxNQ0NVRTk5NzE",
        "city_name": "Cuernavaca"
      },
      "shipping": {
        "free_shipping": true,
        "mode": "me2",
        "tags": [
          "fulfillment",
          "mandatory_free_shipping"
        ],
        "logistic_type": "fulfillment",
        "store_pick_up": false
      },
      "seller_address": {
        "id": "",
        "comment": "",
        "address_line": "",
        "zip_code": "",
        "country": {
          "id": "MX",
          "name": "Mexico"
        },
        "state": {
          "id": "MX-MOR",
          "name": "Morelos"
        },
        "city": {
          "id": "TUxNQ0NVRTk5NzE",
          "name": "Cuernavaca"
        },
        "latitude": "",
        "longitude": ""
      },
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "value_id": "5132844",
          "value_name": "Senwa",
          "values": [],
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "id": "BRAND",
          "name": "Marca",
          "value_struct": null,
          "source": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Condición del ítem",
          "value_id": "2230284",
          "value_name": "Nuevo",
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "ITEM_CONDITION",
          "value_struct": null,
          "values": [],
          "source": 6808261514773724
        },
        {
          "value_id": "5897271",
          "value_name": "Disco S301",
          "value_struct": null,
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "source": 1,
          "id": "MODEL",
          "name": "Modelo",
          "values": []
        },
        {
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "source": 4333789534002961,
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "PACKAGE_LENGTH",
          "name": "Largo del paquete",
          "value_id": null,
          "value_name": "12.5 cm",
          "value_struct": {},
          "values": [
            {
              "id": null,
              "name": "12.5 cm",
              "struct": {},
              "source": 4333789534002961
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Peso del paquete",
          "value_name": "180 g",
          "value_struct": {},
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "PACKAGE_WEIGHT",
          "values": [],
          "source": 4333789534002961,
          "value_id": null
        },
        {
          "id": "PROCESSOR_MODEL",
          "values": [],
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "name": "Modelo del procesador",
          "value_id": "8031815",
          "value_name": "MediaTek MT6261M",
          "value_struct": null,
          "source": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "WEIGHT",
          "name": "Peso",
          "value_name": "71 g",
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "source": 1,
          "value_id": "7389224",
          "value_struct": {
            "number": 71,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "values": [
            {}
          ],
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros"
        }
      ],
      "original_price": null,
      "category_id": "MLM1055",
      "official_store_id": 3540,
      "domain_id": "MLM-CELLPHONES",
      "catalog_product_id": "MLM13429867",
      "tags": [],
      "catalog_listing": true,
      "order_backend": 1
    },
```

Muestro solo un objeto extendido tengo otros 50 objetos igual y quiero iterar cada uno pero solo ciertos datos

estaba usando algo como lo siguiente en mi `success: fuction (data) {` pero no funciona como quiero

```
$.each(data, function() {
   for (var key in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         console.log(key + " -> " + this[key]);
      }
   }
})
```

Gracias

Comment: Gracias por el check! Así otros usuarios podrán saber que la respuesta solventó tu problema en caso de estar en la misma situación :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el array `results` de dos maneras, según lo que necesites:

- Con Array.map() recorres e iteras sobre dicho array, aplicando una función sobre cada elemento, y devolviendo una copia del array procesado en una variable nueva (array nuevo). Es ideal para procesar los datos (por ejemplo, modificar la estructura de cada entrada, hacer algún cómputo, etc). Puedes consultar más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).
- Con Array.forEach() sólo recorres, y suele ser menos potente que `.map`. Es útil y adecuado cuando necesitas recorrer un array aplicando una función a cada elemento (por ejemplo, sumando un campo precio). Puedes consultar más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach).

Igualmente, estos comportamientos podrían realizarse con la función `.reduce`, pero ya queda fuera del ámbito de la pregunta.

Te dejo tu JSON con un ejemplo de mostrar los IDs de `result`. Espero que te pueda servir; cualquier duda, utiliza los comentarios.

```js
const dataMercadoLibre = {
  "site_id": "MLM",
  "paging": {},
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "MLM863465344",
      "site_id": "MLM",
      "title": "Senwa Disco S301 32 Mb Rojo/blanco 32 Mb Ram",
      "seller": {
        "id": 183830593,
        "permalink": null,
        "registration_date": null,
        "car_dealer": false,
        "real_estate_agency": false,
        "tags": null
      },
      "price": 319,
      "prices": {
        "id": "MLM863465344",
        "prices": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "standard",
            "conditions": {
              "context_restrictions": [
              ],
              "start_time": null,
              "end_time": null,
              "eligible": true
            },
            "amount": 319,
            "regular_amount": null,
            "currency_id": "MXN",
            "exchange_rate_context": "DEFAULT",
            "metadata": {
            },
            "last_updated": "2021-01-18T21:08:00Z"
          }
        ],
        "presentation": {
          "display_currency": "MXN"
        },
        "payment_method_prices": [
        ]
      },
      "sale_price": null,
      "currency_id": "MXN",
      "available_quantity": 30,
      "sold_quantity": 0,
      "buying_mode": "buy_it_now",
      "listing_type_id": "gold_special",
      "stop_time": "2041-01-10T04:00:00.000Z",
      "condition": "new",
      "permalink": "https://www.mercadolibre.com.mx/senwa-disco-s301-32-mb-rojoblanco-32-mb-ram/p/MLM13429867",
      "thumbnail": "http://mlm-s1-p.mlstatic.com/889120-MLA41010292648_032020-I.jpg",
      "accepts_mercadopago": true,
      "installments": {
        "quantity": 12,
        "amount": 32.01,
        "rate": 20.4,
        "currency_id": "MXN"
      },
      "address": {
        "state_id": "MX-MOR",
        "state_name": "Morelos",
        "city_id": "TUxNQ0NVRTk5NzE",
        "city_name": "Cuernavaca"
      },
      "shipping": {
        "free_shipping": true,
        "mode": "me2",
        "tags": [
          "fulfillment",
          "mandatory_free_shipping"
        ],
        "logistic_type": "fulfillment",
        "store_pick_up": false
      },
      "seller_address": {
        "id": "",
        "comment": "",
        "address_line": "",
        "zip_code": "",
        "country": {
          "id": "MX",
          "name": "Mexico"
        },
        "state": {
          "id": "MX-MOR",
          "name": "Morelos"
        },
        "city": {
          "id": "TUxNQ0NVRTk5NzE",
          "name": "Cuernavaca"
        },
        "latitude": "",
        "longitude": ""
      },
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "value_id": "5132844",
          "value_name": "Senwa",
          "values": [],
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "id": "BRAND",
          "name": "Marca",
          "value_struct": null,
          "source": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Condición del ítem",
          "value_id": "2230284",
          "value_name": "Nuevo",
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "ITEM_CONDITION",
          "value_struct": null,
          "values": [],
          "source": 6808261514773724
        },
        {
          "value_id": "5897271",
          "value_name": "Disco S301",
          "value_struct": null,
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "source": 1,
          "id": "MODEL",
          "name": "Modelo",
          "values": []
        },
        {
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "source": 4333789534002961,
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "PACKAGE_LENGTH",
          "name": "Largo del paquete",
          "value_id": null,
          "value_name": "12.5 cm",
          "value_struct": {},
          "values": [
            {
              "id": null,
              "name": "12.5 cm",
              "struct": {},
              "source": 4333789534002961
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Peso del paquete",
          "value_name": "180 g",
          "value_struct": {},
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "id": "PACKAGE_WEIGHT",
          "values": [],
          "source": 4333789534002961,
          "value_id": null
        },
        {
          "id": "PROCESSOR_MODEL",
          "values": [],
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros",
          "name": "Modelo del procesador",
          "value_id": "8031815",
          "value_name": "MediaTek MT6261M",
          "value_struct": null,
          "source": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "WEIGHT",
          "name": "Peso",
          "value_name": "71 g",
          "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
          "source": 1,
          "value_id": "7389224",
          "value_struct": {
            "number": 71,
            "unit": "g"
          },
          "values": [
            {}
          ],
          "attribute_group_name": "Otros"
        }
      ],
      "original_price": null,
      "category_id": "MLM1055",
      "official_store_id": 3540,
      "domain_id": "MLM-CELLPHONES",
      "catalog_product_id": "MLM13429867",
      "tags": [],
      "catalog_listing": true,
      "order_backend": 1
    },
  ]
};

console.log('Con .map(): ', dataMercadoLibre.results.map(result => result.id));

dataMercadoLibre.results.forEach(result => console.log('forEach - Id: ', result.id));
```